# Google App Engine deploys incorrect application

Tags: google-app-engine, pydev, aptana3

I am new to the Google App Engine.

I used Aptana Studio 3 on Windows 7 to create a sample GAE application using its PyDev module and the "Ask Login" template.  Aptana created a folder called 'src' which contains the necessary files (app.yaml, asklogin.py).  But when I use the Launcher (from the GAE SDK) to deploy this application, another folder is created at the same level as the original 'src' folder, where the deployer puts in a simple 'hello webapp world' application and deploys that code instead!

During my first test, I did in fact upload a 'hello webapp world' application, but now want to override it w/ the 'Ask Login' application.  But for some reason, the deployer seems to be remembering the original application (some form of hidden cacheing?).

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Google App Launcher make sure that you do NOT "add application", but that you "add existing application" and point that to the src folder that you mentioned. These options can be found in the File menu.

As long as your app.yaml file contains the correct name of the application as registered on GAE you should be good to go.